# Divide a csv file into four different files

Tags: r, csv

I have a dataset `dataset.csv` and an array `v`, which have the same number of rows. An example of dataset:

```
1   1   1   2   3
2   2   1   2   3
3   1   1   1   1
4   2   2   2   1
5   2   2   3   2
6   1   2   3   2
7   2   1   2   2
8   1   1   3   2
9   1   1   3   3
```

An example for array `v`:

```
1
4
2
3
3
1
2
1
4
```

I would like to divide the file `dataset.csv` into four cvs files, according to array `v`. For example, `v[1]=1`, this means that the first row of `dataset.csv` going in the file `dataset-1.csv`; `v[2]=4` this means that the second row of `dataset.csv` going in the file `dataset-4.csv` and so on.

In other words, we have four files, `dataset-1.csv`:

```
1   1   1   2   3
6   1   2   3   2
8   1   1   3   2
```

`dataset-2.csv`:

```
3   1   1   1   1
7   2   1   2   2
```

`dataset-3.csv`:

```
4   2   2   2   1
5   2   2   3   2
```

and `dataset-4.csv`:

```
2   2   1   2   3
9   1   1   3   3
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split`

```
out <- split(df1, v)
out
#$`1`
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  1  1  2  3
#6  6  1  2  3  2
#8  8  1  1  3  2

#$`2`
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#3  3  1  1  1  1
#7  7  2  1  2  2

#$`3`
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#4  4  2  2  2  1
#5  5  2  2  3  2

#$`4`
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#2  2  2  1  2  3
#9  9  1  1  3  3
```

You can save all four files using `Map` and `write.csv`

```
path <- "path/to/file/"
Map(write.csv, x = out, file = paste0(path, "dataset-", names(out), ".csv"))
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "1   1   1   2   3
2   2   1   2   3
3   1   1   1   1
4   2   2   2   1
5   2   2   3   2
6   1   2   3   2
7   2   1   2   2
8   1   1   3   2
9   1   1   3   3", header = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I obtain the following: 
$`1` NULL

$`2`
NULL

$`3`
NULL

$`4`
NULL

Comment: I saw the same output, but the data frames should be there at `path`.